# Is it possible to obtain Iphone or IPad Device Notifications Status

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing a view that need obtain device notification status.

For example, I have a switch button on a view, if device notification status is off, then switch button is off,too.

Comment: check out this http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/